# Navigation doesn't update TabBarView body with a custom widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to use a TabBar and a BottomNavigationBar to control the same TabBarView whose body is a list of custom widget RankingTable (only put one in the demo and using a Text widget as the 2nd child).
My problem is when tapping on navigation bar, it doesn't update the TabBarView body e.g. RankingTable doesn't update; in the demo code below I have put the same data in the table but the date drop down above the table should be formatted differently since I pass in a different formatter into each datatable when navigation bar is tapped. Namely, in the 2nd screenshot, on Nav1, it still shows the same dropdown date format as in the 1st screenshot which is on Nav0.
Screenshot1:
[image]

Screenshot2:
[image]

If I put a simple widget such as Text in the `TabBarView` body, then it updates as expected when tapping on the navigation bar items, not sure whether this implies the problem is my custom `RankingTable` widget.
Also, despite the body doesn't update when tapping on a new item in navigation bar, if I switch tab e.g. from `Tab1` to `Tab2` and switch it back to `Tab1`, then the body gets updated correctly, matching with the corresponding navigation bar item. It feels like the body data did get updated when tapping navigation but it just didn't get rendered.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() => runApp(new Demo());

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  Map<DateTime, List<RankingBase>> _playerDateRanking;
  TabController controller;
  List<_NavigationIconView> _navigationIconViews;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _navigationIconViews = <_NavigationIconView>[
      _NavigationIconView(
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_day),
        title: 'Nav0',
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      _NavigationIconView(
        icon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
        title: 'Nav1',
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        vsync: this,
      ),
    ];

    _playerDateRanking = {
      DateTime(2018, 9, 10): [
        PlayerRanking('Tony', 7, 6, 140, 110, 80),
        PlayerRanking('John', 7, 2, 120, 130, 56),
        PlayerRanking('Mike', 8, 5, 120, 130, 70),
        PlayerRanking('Clar', 6, 2, 100, 134, 63)
      ],
      DateTime(2018, 9, 12): [
        PlayerRanking('Tony', 7, 6, 140, 110, 80),
        PlayerRanking('John', 7, 2, 120, 130, 56),
        PlayerRanking('Mike', 8, 5, 120, 130, 70),
        PlayerRanking('Clare', 6, 2, 100, 134, 63),
        PlayerRanking('Jo', 5, 1, 100, 134, 63)
      ]
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: controller,
            tabs: <Widget>[Text('Tab1'), Text('Tab2')],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: controller, //TabController(length: 2, vsync: this),
          children: <Widget>[
            buildRankingTable(_currentIndex),
            Text('TEst'),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          items: _navigationIconViews.map((x) => x.item).toList(),
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildRankingTable(int currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == 0) {
      return RankingTable(_playerDateRanking, dateFormatter: 'yMMMEd');
    } else if (currentIndex == 1) {
      return RankingTable(_playerDateRanking,
          dateFormatter: 'MMMM'); // different date formatter here!
    }
    return Text('TODO...');
  }
}

class _NavigationIconView {
  _NavigationIconView({
    Widget icon,
    //Widget activeIcon,
    String title,
    Color color,
    TickerProvider vsync,
  })  : _icon = icon,
        _color = color,
        _title = title,
        item = new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: icon,
          //   activeIcon: activeIcon,
          title: new Text(title),
          backgroundColor: color,
        ),
        controller = new AnimationController(
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
          vsync: vsync,
        ) {
    _animation = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
    );
  }
  final Widget _icon;
  final Color _color;
  final String _title;
  final BottomNavigationBarItem item;
  final AnimationController controller;
  CurvedAnimation _animation;
}

class PlayerRanking extends RankingBase {
  String name;
  PlayerRanking(this.name, played, won, pointsWon, pointsLost, duration)
      : super(played, won, pointsWon, pointsLost, duration);
}

class RankingBase {
  DateTime date;
  int won;
  int played;
  int duration;
  int pointsWon;
  int pointsLost;
  double get winRatio => won / played;
  RankingBase(
      this.played, this.won, this.pointsWon, this.pointsLost, this.duration);

  static int performanceSort(RankingBase rb1, RankingBase rb2) {
    if (rb1.winRatio > rb2.winRatio) return -1;
    if (rb1.winRatio < rb2.winRatio) return 1;
    if (rb1.played > rb2.played) return -1;
    if (rb2.played == rb2.played) return rb1.pointsWon.compareTo(rb2.pointsWon);
    return -1;
  }
}

// this puts a scrollable datatable and optionally a header widget into a ListView
class RankingTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<DateTime, List<RankingBase>> rankingMap;
  final bool hasHeaderWidget;
  final String dateFormatter;
  //final bool isPlayer;
  RankingTable(this.rankingMap,
      {this.dateFormatter, this.hasHeaderWidget = true});

  @override
  _RankingTableState createState() => _RankingTableState(this.rankingMap,
      dateFormatter: this.dateFormatter, hasHeaderWidget: this.hasHeaderWidget);
}

class _RankingTableState extends State<RankingTable> {
  Map<DateTime, List<RankingBase>> rankingMap;
  final bool hasHeaderWidget;
  final String dateFormatter;
  //final bool isPlayer;
  _RankingTableState(this.rankingMap,
      {this.dateFormatter, this.hasHeaderWidget = true});

  DateTime _selectedDate;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedDate = rankingMap.keys.last;
  }

  DataTable buildRankingTable() {
    rankingMap[_selectedDate].sort(RankingBase.performanceSort);
    String nameOrPair =
        rankingMap[_selectedDate].first is PlayerRanking ? 'Name' : 'Pair';
    int rank = 1;

    return DataTable(
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(label: Text('Rank')),
        DataColumn(label: Text(nameOrPair)),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Played')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Win Ratio')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Points Won-Loss')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Duration')),
      ],
      rows: rankingMap[_selectedDate].map((RankingBase pr) {
        DataCell titleCell;
        if (pr is PlayerRanking)
          titleCell = DataCell(Text('${pr.name}'));
        else {
          // var pair = pr as PairRanking;
          // titleCell = DataCell(Text('${pair.player1Name}\n${pair.player2Name}'));
        }
        return DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text('${rank++}')),
          titleCell,
          DataCell(Text('${pr.played}')),
          DataCell(Text('${NumberFormat("0.##%").format(pr.won / pr.played)}')),
          DataCell(Text('${pr.pointsWon} - ${pr.pointsLost}')),
          DataCell(Text('${pr.duration}')),
        ]);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> childrenWidgets = [];
    if (hasHeaderWidget) {
      var dateDropdown = DropdownButton<DateTime>(
        items: rankingMap.keys
            .map((date) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                      '${DateFormat(dateFormatter).format(date)}'), //yMMMEd
                  value: date,
                ))
            .toList(),
        value: _selectedDate,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedDate = value;
          });
        },
      );
      childrenWidgets.add(dateDropdown);
    }

    childrenWidgets.add(SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: buildRankingTable(),
    ));

    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      children: childrenWidgets,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `RankingTable` doesn't change is because *build* method in the code uses fields (rankingMap, dateFormatter, etc.) stored in your state. 
When `StatefulWidget` is created for the first time, it also instantiates relevant `State` object which then builds your widget in *build* method. Every time you call *setState* method, Flutter **recreates `Widget` from scratch, whereas `State` object is being persisted**.

> Widgets are temporary objects, used to construct a presentation of the application in its current state. State objects on the other hand are persistent between calls to build(), allowing them to remember information.

This means, every time `RankingTable` widget is created, your *build* method in `_RankingTableState` makes use of the same values passed in the constructor/assigned in *initState* (even though widget object contains updated fields values). On the other hand, when you naviagte back and forth by using the `TabBar`, state object is recreated with current *dateFormatter* - that's why the table is updated in this scenario.

To make it work as intended, you should remove all final fields from your *state* object and refer directly to its *widget* to get all necessary values:

```
class RankingTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<DateTime, List<RankingBase>> rankingMap;
  final bool hasHeaderWidget;
  final String dateFormatter;
  RankingTable(this.rankingMap,
      {this.dateFormatter, this.hasHeaderWidget = true});

  @override
  _RankingTableState createState() => _RankingTableState();
}

class _RankingTableState extends State<RankingTable> {
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedDate = widget.rankingMap.keys.last;
  }

  DataTable buildRankingTable() {
    widget.rankingMap[_selectedDate].sort(RankingBase.performanceSort);
    String nameOrPair =
        widget.rankingMap[_selectedDate].first is PlayerRanking ? 'Name' : 'Pair';
    int rank = 1;

    return DataTable(
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(label: Text('Rank')),
        DataColumn(label: Text(nameOrPair)),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Played')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Win Ratio')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Points Won-Loss')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Duration')),
      ],
      rows: widget.rankingMap[_selectedDate].map((RankingBase pr) {
        DataCell titleCell;
        if (pr is PlayerRanking)
          titleCell = DataCell(Text('${pr.name}'));
        else {
          // var pair = pr as PairRanking;
          // titleCell = DataCell(Text('${pair.player1Name}\n${pair.player2Name}'));
        }
        return DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text('${rank++}')),
          titleCell,
          DataCell(Text('${pr.played}')),
          DataCell(Text('${NumberFormat("0.##%").format(pr.won / pr.played)}')),
          DataCell(Text('${pr.pointsWon} - ${pr.pointsLost}')),
          DataCell(Text('${pr.duration}')),
        ]);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> childrenWidgets = [];
    if (widget.hasHeaderWidget) {
      var dateDropdown = DropdownButton<DateTime>(
        items: widget.rankingMap.keys
            .map((date) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                      '${DateFormat(widget.dateFormatter).format(date)}'), //yMMMEd
                  value: date,
                ))
            .toList(),
        value: _selectedDate,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedDate = value;
          });
        },
      );
      childrenWidgets.add(dateDropdown);
    }

    childrenWidgets.add(SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: buildRankingTable(),
    ));

    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      children: childrenWidgets,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't get why when switching `TabBar`, the `RankingTable` state gets recreated? Does it have something to do with how `TabBar` works?

Comment: When you switch them, an old tab is removed from the `WidgetTree` and new one is inserted - in such case widget creates new state object by calling *createState* method. [This](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) might give you better understanding on how and when new state is instantiated.

Comment: Which isn't the case if you only rebuild your widget via *setState* - it still remains in the `WidgetTree` so the state doesn't get recreated.

Comment: Yes, got you now! That makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in your `State`.

First, there is no need for a constructor in your state. You can access the variables of your widget by calling `widget.youFinalField`.

The problem is: when you return a `new RankingTable` the underlying `state` is not recreated but rebuilt (the `build` and the `didUpdateWidget` methods are called).
Because you passed you variables in the construct (which is only used the very first time) your formatter doesn't update.

The solution is pretty simple, instead of using a constructor in your `state` just access the variables through the widget.

Working code state code:

```
    // this puts a scrollable datatable and optionally a header widget into a ListView
class RankingTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<DateTime, List<RankingBase>> rankingMap;
  final bool hasHeaderWidget;
  final String dateFormatter;
  //final bool isPlayer;
  RankingTable(this.rankingMap,
      {this.dateFormatter, this.hasHeaderWidget = true});

  @override
  _RankingTableState createState() => _RankingTableState();
}

class _RankingTableState extends State<RankingTable> {


  DateTime _selectedDate;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedDate = widget.rankingMap.keys.last;
  }



  DataTable buildRankingTable() {
    widget.rankingMap[_selectedDate].sort(RankingBase.performanceSort);
    String nameOrPair =
    widget.rankingMap[_selectedDate].first is PlayerRanking ? 'Name' : 'Pair';
    int rank = 1;

    return DataTable(
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(label: Text('Rank')),
        DataColumn(label: Text(nameOrPair)),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Played')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Win Ratio')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Points Won-Loss')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Duration')),
      ],
      rows: widget.rankingMap[_selectedDate].map((RankingBase pr) {
        DataCell titleCell;
        if (pr is PlayerRanking)
          titleCell = DataCell(Text('${pr.name}'));
        else {
          // var pair = pr as PairRanking;
          // titleCell = DataCell(Text('${pair.player1Name}\n${pair.player2Name}'));
        }
        return DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text('${rank++}')),
          titleCell,
          DataCell(Text('${pr.played}')),
          DataCell(Text('')),
          DataCell(Text('${pr.pointsWon} - ${pr.pointsLost}')),
          DataCell(Text('${pr.duration}')),
        ]);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> childrenWidgets = [];
    if (widget.hasHeaderWidget) {
      var dateDropdown = DropdownButton<DateTime>(
        items: widget.rankingMap.keys
            .map((date) => DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(
              '$date ${widget.dateFormatter}'), //yMMMEd
          value: date,
        ))
            .toList(),
        value: _selectedDate,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedDate = value;
          });
        },
      );
      childrenWidgets.add(dateDropdown);
    }

    childrenWidgets.add(SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: buildRankingTable(),
    ));

    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      children: childrenWidgets,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple... but this again shows how important to understand how things work internally. For flutter, I think understanding state management is a must.

Comment: Sorry, could only accept one answer. Thanks again for your help. Look forward to more flutter internal articles from you!